# Parent directory symbol not working in html

Tags: python, django, directory, atom-editor, web-development-server

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Exam Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../static/css/teststyle.css">
 </head>
```

Im using this code in exam folder and i wanted to go to parent directory so i used ../../ but it is showing the below error

Not Found: /exam/static/css/teststyle.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your template add `{% load static %}` and to add your css you can use `{% static 'css/teststyle.css' %}`.

```
{% load static %}

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Exam Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/teststyle.css' %}">
</head>
```

In your main `urls.py` add

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and in your `settings.py` add

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Kindly mark this answer as `accepted`